# Event onmousenter

Tags: javascript

Seguinte to criando um site e na parte de galeria eu criei uma função    para quando passar o mouse sobre a imagem criar uma margem, mas, a    imagem ficar ligeiramente maior. Gostaria de saber se seria possível    manter ela estática?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor essa margem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso resolve seu problema [Box-sizing](http://sergiolopes.org/css-box-sizing-border-box/), apenas `CSS`:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Uma vez que os elementos construtores `HTML` são caixas, deveria ser considerado que, o tamanho da caixa inclui sua borda, mas não é o que acontece, então a propriedade `box-sizing` resolve o problema, ela mantém o tamanho definido, por exemplo `width:50%` mesmo com uma borda `border:10px solid;`, a caixa ainda terá apenas 50% e não 50%+20px.

Comment: Seria melhor que você desse pelo menos um exemplo com um resumo, e usar o link como referência, ou se não mover a resposta para a sessão de comentário

Comment: @Sveen ainda sou novato, mas obrigado pelo conselho, vou procurar ser mais calro nas respostas, sempre fazia pesquisas aqui no StackOverflow, a anos, mas só agora resolvi integrar ao grupo de participação, quero fazer o melhor para ajudar. Gratidão.

Answer (score 0):

A imagem tem 333x400, no hover diminui 4px de cada dimensão que corresponde ao dobro da espessura da borda.

```css
.efeito:hover{
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
   width: 329px;
   height: 396px;
}
```

```html
<img class="efeito" src="https://marketingdeconteudo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/giphy-7.gif">
```

```
<img class="efeito" src="https://marketingdeconteudo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/giphy-7.gif">
```

Aqui com borda = 10px

```css
.efeito:hover{
border: 10px solid #ff0000;
 width: 313px;
 height: 380px;
}
```

```html
<img class="efeito" src="https://marketingdeconteudo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/giphy-7.gif">
```